# Matching last non-private IP address in an X-Forwarded-For header

Tags: regex, varnish

I have the following conundrum. Due to the way our server stack is laid out: `ELB -> Varnish -> Apache`, I need Varnish to extract the rightmost non-private IP address from the `X-Forwarded-For` header (which is properly set by the ELB and can be trusted).

I am already using the following regular expression to get the last IP address in the string. My problem has been trying to figure out how to filter the private IP addresses.

```
((\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}))(?!.*(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}))
```

Here is the private IP filter I have been testing with.

```
(^127\.)|(^10\.)|(^172\.1[6-9]\.)|(^172\.2[0-9]\.)|(^172\.3[0-1]\.)|(^192\.168\.)
```

Please note that I am using a regular expression VMOD, which allows me to access back references.

Check out the example below, which should illustrate what I am trying to accomplish:

```
92.58.12.100, 10.0.120.5                  -> 92.58.12.100
172.24.10.15, 127.0.0.1, 95.58.12.100     -> 95.58.12.100
92.58.12.100                              -> 92.58.12.100
```

Also, here is a [link](http://www.regexr.com/3cpg9) to a RegExr example. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use this pattern

```
.*\b(?!10|127)(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})
```

[Demo](http://regexr.com/3cpgi)

Comment: More precisely, for varnish: `set req.http.X-Real-IP = regsub(req.http.X-Forwarded-For, ".*\b(?!10|127)(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}).*", "\1");`

Answer (score 2):

alpha bravo's answer points in the right direction, but is missing the correct parsing of the private IP address space (for example its missing a dot right after the prefixes to exclude and it will match any address beginning with 10 as private, including 101.*.*.* which is not).

The IPv4 private address space is:

```
10.0.0.0 to 10.255.255.255
172.16.0.0 to 172.31.255.255
192.168.0.0 to 192.168.255.255
```

Modifying alpha bravo's answer to include these addresses (and the special addresses that begin with 127.*) yields to the following regex:

```
.*\b(?!127\.|10\.|172\.1[6-9]\.|172\.2[0-9]\.|172\.3[0-1]\.|192\.168\.)(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}
```